# How to implement created_at and updated_at column using Room Persistence ORM tools in android

Tags: java, android, orm, android-room, sql-timestamp

How can I implement `created_at` and `updated_at` columns using Room Persistence ORM tools in Android, that can update the timestamp automatically when creating or updating a row in a table?

Comment: With triggers which can be added with inside `RoomDatabase.Callback.onCreate`

Comment: Can anybody show an example of a model entity that can use this two fields?

Answer (score 8):

I've research many sites, but still not found any results can handle `middleware` or something like `callbacks` when we `Query`, `Insert`, `Update`, or `Delete`,... methods from `DAO`s.

As @selvin said, `RoomDatabase.Callback` interface only call when database created in first time. So, use that interface is incorrect way.
So, may be the way below is a trick for me, hope this will help you:

#### 1. We need to create a `BaseModel`

This model to sure that all models in database always available columns `creation_date` and `modification_date`.

```
abstract class BaseModel: Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) 
    @Expose
    var id: Long = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    @SerializedName(value = "description")
    var description: String? = null

    @ColumnInfo(name = "creation_date")
    @SerializedName(value = "creation_date")
    var creationDate: Date = Date(System.currentTimeMillis())

    @ColumnInfo(name = "modification_date")
    @SerializedName(value = "modification_date")
    var modificationDate: Date = Date(System.currentTimeMillis())

}
```

#### 2. Create an `BaseDAO`

Inside `BaseDAO`, I also create a wrapper class named `DAOWrapper`, this class will store all helpful methods that we will use to process data like "middleware" before interact model's data to DAO.

**So, why we don't create methods inside `BaseDAO`?**
-> We cannot do that! use that way will conflict android architecture and also we will have error from compiler (all methods declared in DAO object requires annotation `Update`, `Query`,...).

```
interface BaseDAO<T> where T: BaseModel {

    fun getAll(): List<T>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
    fun insert(modelData: T)

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
    fun update(modelData: T)

    companion object {

        open class DAOWrapper<P, T>(private val daoInstance: T) where T: BaseDAO<P>, P: BaseModel {

            fun insertWithTimestapData(modelData: P) {
                modelData.modificationDate = Date(System.currentTimeMillis())
                this@DAOWrapper.daoInstance.insert(modelData)
            }

        }

    }

}
```

#### 3. To use the `DAOWrapper`

```
val appDatabase = // Do something to get RoomDatabase instance...
val exampleDao = appDatabase.exampleDAO()
val exampleDaoWrapper = BaseDAO.Companion.DAOWrapper(exampleDao)

val exampleModel = ExampleModel(name = "Example Name")
exampleDaoWrapper.insertWithTimestapData(exampleModel)
```

#### References

Below is example instance of RoomDatabase and example model I used in code above:

```
/** ExampleModel.kt */
@Entity(
    tableName = "examples",
    indices = [Index(value = arrayOf("name"), unique = true)]
)
class ExampleModel(): BaseModel() {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    @SerializedName(value = "name")
    var name: String = String()

    @Ignore
    constructor(name: String): this() {
        this@ExampleModel.name = name
    }

}


/** ExampleDAO.kt */
@Dao
interface ExampleDAO: BaseDAO<ExampleModel> {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM `examples`")
    override fun getAll(): List<ExampleModel>

}


/** AppDatabase.kt **/
@Database(entities = [ExampleModel::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun exampleDAO(): ExampleDAO

    companion object {
        private var databaseInstance: AppDatabase? = null
        public const val DatabaseName: String = "app_database"

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            this@Companion.destroyAndCreateNewInstanceIfNeeded(context)
            return this@Companion.databaseInstance!!
        }

        fun destroyAndCreateNewInstanceIfNeeded(context: Context) {
            synchronized(AppDatabase::class) {
                this@Companion.databaseInstance?.close()
                this@Companion.databaseInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    this@Companion.DatabaseName
                ).build()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It will be better if you write in Java or logic flow. (It was tagged with Java)

Comment: https://medium.com/@stephenja/timestamps-with-android-room-f3fd57b48250

Comment: @AsifMohammadMollah I have added a Java example :)

Answer (score 5):

To follow on the above with a Java example.

**The Base entity for all the Room entities**
This maps to a table that contains an id, created_at and updated_at column.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "created_at", defaultValue = "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    @TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
    private Date createdAt;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "updated_at", defaultValue = "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    @TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
    private Date updatedAt;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }
}
```

**The Room Date TypeConverter**
This converts Java Dates into numbers which can be saved in the sqlite database.

```
public class DateConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public static Date toDate(Long timestamp) {
        if (timestamp == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Date(timestamp);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Long toTimestamp(Date date) {
        if (date == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return date.getTime();
    }
}
```

**The abstract BaseDao**
This Dao implements all the basic Insert, Update and Delete methods.

```
@Dao
public abstract class AbstractBaseEntityDao<T extends BaseEntity> {

    @Insert
    public abstract long actualInsert(T t);

    public long insert(T t) {
        t.setCreatedAt(new Date());
        t.setUpdatedAt(new Date());
        return actualInsert(t);
    }

    @Insert
    public abstract List<Long> actualInsertAll(List<T> ts);

    public List<Long> insertAll(List<T> ts) {
        if (ts != null) {
            for (T t : ts) {
                t.setCreatedAt(new Date());
                t.setUpdatedAt(new Date());
            }
        }
        return actualInsertAll(ts);
    }

    @Update
    public abstract void actualUpdate(T t);

    public void update(T t) {
        t.setUpdatedAt(new Date());
        actualUpdate(t);
    }

    @Update
    public abstract void actualUpdateAll(List<T> ts);

    public void updateAll(List<T> ts) {
        if (ts != null) {
            for (T t : ts) {
                t.setUpdatedAt(new Date());
            }
        }
        actualUpdateAll(ts);
    }

    @Delete
    public abstract void delete(T t);

    @Delete
    public abstract void deleteAll(List<T> ts);
}
```

**User and UserDao**
Here is an example of a concrete Entity and Dao for a User (typical use-case).

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public User() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@Dao
public abstract class UserDao extends AbstractBaseEntityDao<User> {

    @Query("select * from users")
    public abstract List<User> getAllUsers();
}
```

**How to insert a User**
This will use the AbstractBaseEntityDao which sets the created_at and updated_at timestamps.

Note: do not do this on the UI thread!!

```
YourDatabase database = YourDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
UserDao userDao = database.userDao();
long userId = userDao.insert(userToAdd);
userToAdd.setId(userId);
```

**How to update the User**

```
YourDatabase database = YourDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
UserDao userDao = database.userDao();
userDao.update(userToEdit);
```

Comment: all of that boilerplate code for something most would consider a routine database procedure

Comment: Adding `@TypeConverters()` annotation to the field directly did not work in my case. I had to add it to either an `@Entity`, a `@Dao`, or a `@Database`.