# Work with mutually exclusive values in the database

Tags: android, database, android-room

I have db for storing tasks. Task may be repeatable, it can be scheduled on few days of week or a few dates.

Structure:

```
enum class ScheduleType(val value: Int) {
    NONE(-1),
    DATE(0),
    WEEKDAY(1);
}

@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = User::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("authorId"),
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )]
)
data class Task(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) //TODO do not auto generated
    val id: Int? = null,
    val type: ScheduleType,
    val title: String,
    val body: String?,
    val authorId: Int,
    val isFavorite: Boolean = false,
    val createdDate: ZonedDateTime,
    val updatedDate: ZonedDateTime? = null,
    val lastSyncDate: ZonedDateTime? = null,
    val deletedDate: ZonedDateTime? = null,
)

@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = Task::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("taskId"),
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )],
)
data class ScheduleTask(
    @PrimaryKey var taskId: Int = ID_UNSPECIFIED,
    val time: LocalTime,
    val isRepeat: Boolean = false,
)

@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = ScheduleTask::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("taskId"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("taskId"),
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )],
    primaryKeys = ["taskId", "weekDay"]
)
data class ScheduleWeekWithTime(
    var taskId: Int = ID_UNSPECIFIED,
    val weekDay: WeekDays,
    val lastScheduleDate: ZonedDateTime? = null,
    val lastDoneDate: ZonedDateTime? = null,
    val lastDelayedTime: ZonedDateTime? = null,
    val lastDelayValue: Long = 0
)

@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = ScheduleTask::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("taskId"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("taskId"),
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )],
    primaryKeys = ["taskId", "date"]
)
data class ScheduleDateWithTime(
    var taskId: Int = ID_UNSPECIFIED,
    val date: LocalDate,
    val lastScheduleDate: ZonedDateTime? = null,
    val lastDoneDate: ZonedDateTime? = null,
    val lastDelayedTime: ZonedDateTime? = null,
    val lastDelayValue: Long = 0
)
```

Is it normal to have the same attributes in ScheduleDateWithTime and ScheduleWeekWithTime like "lastScheduleDate, lastDoneDate.." ? Is there a way to store them together in one table or there can be more workable structure of db for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it normal to have the same attributes in ScheduleDateWithTime and ScheduleWeekWithTime like "lastScheduleDate, lastDoneDate.." ?

Not really, there is a term called [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) (normalised) used with databases where the idea is to not replicate data.

It would appear that you would be repeating not only the dates but also the tasks, thus the structure is not normalised.

> Is there a way to store them together in one table or there can be more workable structure of db for it?

You could probably use a better structure (schema).

The following may be worth considering (native SQLite used).

First the **TASK** table (note no dates just the task specific data):-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS task (
    taskid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    title TEXT, 
    body TEXT, 
    isfavourite INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 
    duration INTEGER DEFAULT (5 * 60) /* 5 minute default duration */
);
```

- duration added assuming that a task takes a certain amount of time (in seconds)

Next for determining the scheduling of the TASKS a table for the schedule **RULE**s:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rule (
    ruleid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    taskid_map INTEGER REFERENCES task(taskid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    startdate INTEGER DEFAULT (strftime('%s','now')),
    untildate INTEGER DEFAULT (strftime('%s','2100-12-31 23:59:59')),
    lastdate INTEGER DEFAULT  0,
    scheduled_count INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    multiplier INTEGER DEFAULT 1,
    frequency INTEGER DEFAULT 1 /* 0 = does not repeat, 1 = daily, 2 = weekly, 3 = monthly, 4 = annually */,
    limiter INTEGER DEFAULT 0 /* limit by number of times, 0 = no limit */
);
```

- a little complex
- all dates as a unix date (number of seconds) are stored as an integer (Long), thus they can be easily manipulated using the built in [SQLite Date/Time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).
- frequency is used to indicate whether or not the rule (for a task) repeats or not.

  - 0 if it doesn't repeat and is thus a one off instance of the task. Otherwise a number that equates to the frequency of the repetition (the UI would cater for days of the week)

    - you could have multiple rules for days of the week with a weekly frequency,
  - multiplier is used in conjunction with the frequency e.g. a multiplier of 10 and 1 (days) would have the TASK repeat every 10 days
  - note that the Foreign Key has been defined at the column level (simpler), Room would generate the SQL a table level definition (i.e. `column definitions, FOREIGN KEY (taskid_map) REFERENCES task(taskid)`)

Using the above then a few **TASK**s could be added using (equivalent to an `@Insert`):-

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO task VALUES 
    (1,'T1','T1 blah',1,(10 * 60)),
    (2,'T2','T2 blah',0,(30 * 60)),
    (10,'T10','T10 blah',1,(7 * 60)),
    (3,'T3','T3 blah',0,(22 * 60)),
    (4,'T4','T4 blah',1,(10 * 60 * 60))
;
```

Then some **RULE**s (note that due to defaults being utilised that an `@Insert` could not be used but an `@Query` would be required; although setting the vals/vars could be used with an `@Insert`):-

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO rule (taskid_map,startdate,untildate,frequency,multiplier,limiter) VALUES
    (1,strftime('%s','2023-10-28 12:05:30'),strftime('%s','2024-10-28 12:05:30'),2,1,9999)
    ,(1,strftime('%s','2023-10-30 15:10:00'),strftime('%s','2024-10-28 12:05:30'),3,1,9999)
    ,(2,strftime('%s','2023-10-28 11:04:00'),strftime('%s','2100-10-28 12:05:30'),1,4,9999)
    ,(4,strftime('%s','2023-10-28 11:04:00'),strftime('%s','2100-10-28 12:05:30'),0,4,9999)
    ,(10,strftime('%s','2023-11-01 09:04:00'),strftime('%s','2100-10-28 12:05:30'),2,2,9999)
    ,(10,strftime('%s','2023-11-03 10:07:00'),strftime('%s','2100-10-28 12:05:30'),2,19,9999)
    ,(10,strftime('%s','1971-11-01 06:14:00'),strftime('%s','2100-10-28 12:05:30'),2,4,9999)
    
;
```

- [this explains why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59340430/android-room-defaultvalue-current-timestamp-does-not-work) `@Insert` cannot be used for DEFAULT values

With the above, then the data in the data base would be:-

[image]

and

[image]

- note how the dates are stored as integers thus using the minimum amount of storage (could be less if seconds were dropped, but then that would mean more complicated queries)

Although complex, consider the following query:-

```
SELECT 
    task.title,
    task.body,
    'etc' AS another,
    /* Generate a descriptive representation of the repeat factors */ 
    CASE frequency WHEN 0 THEN 'does not repeat' ELSE 
    'repeats every '||multiplier||' '|| CASE frequency  
        WHEN 1 THEN 'days'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Weeks'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Months'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Years'
        ELSE '????'
        END
    END
    ||' starting on '||
    CASE (CAST(strftime('%w',startdate,'unixepoch') AS INTEGER))
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Sunday'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Monday'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Tuesday'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Wednesday'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Thursday'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Friday'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Saturday'
        ELSE 'oooops'
    END 
    ||' '||datetime(startdate,'unixepoch') AS repeat_deescriptive
FROM task JOIN rule ON rule.taskid_map = task.taskid;
```

This, using the data inserted above, results in:-

[image]

i.e.

- Task T1 has the 2 rules associated with it
- Task T2 has a single rule
- Task T4 has a single non-repeating rule (frequency 0)
- Task T10 has 3 rules

There would then be a table for the schedule, perhaps (for example):-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schedule (
    taskid_map INTEGER REFERENCES task(taskid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    starts INTEGER,
    ends INTEGER,
    status INTEGER DEFAULT 0 /* .... 99 = complete */,
    PRIMARY KEY (taskid_map,starts)
);
```

- start would be the date/time of the schedule instance
- end would probably be the duration added to the start, although it could be generated on the fly
- note the composite primary key, using an insert with an OnConflictStategy.IGNORE would probably be used to supress duplicate issues (potentially the the TASK's lastdate column could be done away with depending upon how the schedule is populated)

---

**Additional**

---

The following demonstrates how the flexibility of SQLite could be used to then create a schedule using SQL only.

- CTE stands for Common Table Expression i.e. a temporary table, it's existence limited to the execution of the query.
- note that recursion is used (aka a recursive CTE), like any recursion the looping MUST be ended (LIMIT can be used and/or a WHERE clause).
- note that the data has been changed to reduce the massive number of  rows generated.

First the data (Rule rows) inserted used to demonstrate is now (task rows unchanged):-

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO rule (taskid_map,startdate,untildate,frequency,multiplier,limiter) VALUES
    (1,strftime('%s','2023-10-28 12:05:30'),strftime('%s','2024-10-28 12:05:30'),2,1,9999)
    ,(1,strftime('%s','2023-10-30 15:10:00'),strftime('%s','2024-10-28 12:05:30'),3,1,9999)
    ,(2,strftime('%s','2023-10-28 11:04:00'),strftime('%s','2100-10-28 12:05:30'),1,4,9999)
    ,(4,strftime('%s','2023-10-28 11:04:00'),strftime('%s','2100-10-28 12:05:30'),1,4,9999)
    ,(10,strftime('%s','2023-11-01 09:04:00'),strftime('%s','2100-10-28 12:05:30'),2,2,9999)
    ,(10,strftime('%s','2022-11-03 10:07:00'),strftime('%s','2100-10-28 12:05:30'),2,19,9999)
    ,(10,strftime('%s','2021-11-01 06:14:00'),strftime('%s','2100-10-28 12:05:30'),2,4,9999)
    ,(10,strftime('%s','2022-11-01 06:14:00'),strftime('%s','2030-10-28 12:05:30'),5,5,9999)
    
;
```

i.e. the dates are in a smaller range (it might be prudent to delete rules that are out of use)

Now the recursive query:-

```
WITH
    /* This CTE is used to allow a single definition of the parameters passed, but for the parameter(s) to be used multiple time
        as such in Room you could code (for example):-
            cte_parms(schedule_start,schedule_end) AS (
                SELECT strftime('%s',:schedule_start),strftime('%s',:schedule_end,'+'||:schedule_duration_in_days||' days')
        in which case the function signature could be 
            ....(schedule_start: String, schedule_end: String, schedule_duration_in_days: Int) {....}
    */
    cte_parms(schedule_start,schedule_end) AS (
        SELECT strftime('%s','2023-10-20'),strftime('%s','2023-10-29','+30 days')
    ),
    /* The recursive CTE */
    /* First the initial data (all the rules)*/
    cte_ischedule AS (
        SELECT * FROM rule 
        /* Now recursively create additional data using the frequency and multiplier to calculate the startdate of the task */
        /* i.e. for each initial row an additional row is created, and added that added row then drives another addition .... forever */
        UNION ALL SELECT 
            ruleid, taskid_map, 
            (
                SELECT strftime('%s',startdate,'unixepoch','+'||
                    CASE frequency 
                        WHEN 1 THEN multiplier||' days'
                        WHEN 2 THEN (multiplier * 7)||' days'
                        WHEN 3 THEN multiplier||' months'
                        WHEN 4 THEN multiplier||' years'
                    ELSE '0 days'
                END
                )
            ),
        untildate,
        lastdate,
        scheduled_count+1,
        multiplier,
        frequency,
        limiter
        FROM cte_ischedule
        WHERE startdate < (SELECT schedule_end FROM cte_parms) AND startdate <= untildate /* warning perhaps unsafe to rely just on this to end recursion */
        ORDER BY taskid_map, ruleid, startdate 
        LIMIT 2000000 /* say with 20000 LIMIT not all are caterered for (warning takes nearly 10 seconds) */
    )
/* could be an INSERT (probably  OR IGNORE) rather than SELECT */ 
SELECT 
    (SELECT datetime(schedule_start,'unixepoch') FROM cte_parms) AS SCH_STRT, 
    (SELECT datetime(schedule_end,'unixepoch') FROM cte_parms) AS SCHD_END,title, 
    datetime(startdate,'unixepoch') AS startdate, 
    datetime(untildate,'unixepoch') AS untildate, 
    'Every '||
    CASE frequency
        WHEN 1 THEN multiplier||' days'
        WHEN 2 THEN (multiplier * 7)||' days'
        WHEN 3 THEN multiplier||' months'
        WHEN 4 THEN multiplier||' years'
        ELSE '????'
    END AS freq,
    'RuleID is '||ruleid AS fromRule
FROM cte_ischedule JOIN task ON taskid_map = task.taskid
WHERE startdate BETWEEN (SELECT schedule_start FROM cte_parms) AND (SELECT schedule_end FROM cte_parms);
```

- Note that for each added rule (as opposed to the original rule), the **startdate** is calculated based upon the previous row (i.e. the multipler and frequency being applied via a `strftime` modifier (so SQLite's `strftime` function does the calculation)).

  - the count is also increased, BUT note that this is not considered when scheduling *(to not introduce further complexity)*
  - saying that the freq column is an unnecessary complexity but helps to see what is going on in the resultant output.

When the above is run then the result is:-

[image]

- i.e. the tasks that fit into the scheduled window defined by the values passed into cte_parms

  - note that extensive checking has not been undertaken

***Cautionary Note***

The above assumes regeneration of the entire schedule, which may not be required if say you are just adding a new task when a predecessor has been completed (in which case the last task can be the start point as opposed to the first ever task/rule). As it stands the above can(does) produce a great number of rows in cte_ischedule

- the above is only intended as what can be possible, extensive testing has not been undertaken (***obviously extensive testing should be the case for any App that is to be distributed***)
- you may wish to refer to https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html
- in the example the ***rouge rule*** `(10,strftime('%s','2022-11-01 06:14:00'),strftime('%s','2030-10-28 12:05:30'),5,5,9999)` causes an issue in that it's startdate is NEVER adjusted/increased and hence the LIMIT only applies to stop the recursion (without that rule then rather than an endless number of rows in cte_ischedule only 44 rows are extracted)

  - perhaps, in the case of a rouge rule, rather than adding 0 days, the number of days in the scheduled period should be added
  - perhaps the invalid frequency could excluded when extracting the data from the rule table
  - perhaps such an invalid rule could never be added in the first place